# How to get list of all collections in a DocumentDB document?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have created a lot of collections in a DocumentDB database. How can I retrieve the list of existing collections in the database?

I have just started exploring DocumentDb from the [official documentation](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/documentdb-sql-query/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The short answer is: you can't retrieve a list of collections inside a document. You can, however, retrieve a list of collection inside a database.

Here's a look at the DocumentDB resource model:
[image]

Looking at the DocumentDB resource model - databases contain collections, which in turn contain stored procedures, triggers, UDFs, and documents.

You can query a list of collections under a given database by using the DocumentDB Client or the REST API. Here's an example in .NET:

```
DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), authKey);

Database database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery("SELECT * FROM d WHERE d.id = \"[YOUR_DATABASE_ID]\"").AsEnumerable().First();

List<DocumentCollection> collections = client.CreateDocumentCollectionQuery((String)database.SelfLink).ToList();
```

References:

[DocumentDB Resource Model and Concepts](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-resources/)

[DocumentDB .NET Code Samples](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Azure-DocumentDB-NET-Code-6b3da8af/sourcecode?fileId=124150&pathId=1486572027)